# conditional expected number of success interpretation

Tags: conditional-expectation, binomial-distribution

Suppose $f(k,n,\rho)$ is the pmf for the binomial distribution, then
$$\sum_{r=0}^nf(r,n,\rho)r$$
is the expected number of successes. My question is, how can I interpret
$$\sum_{r=M}^nf(r,n,\rho)r?$$
It's not the expected number of successes given there are at least $M$ successes... at least I don't think so.
Follow up Question: Is there any interpretation to
$$\frac{\sum_{r=M}^nf(r,n,\rho)r}{f(M-1,n,\rho)}?$$
Many thanks for all your help!

Comment: Don't know about the second formula, but it you have a quiz game in which you get one coin for every correctly answered question, there are $n$ questions, the probability of a correct answer for any question is $\rho$ (independently across the questions) *and you can only keep your money if you answered correctly at least $M$ questions*, then $$\sum_{r=M}^nf(r,n,\rho)r$$ is your expected earning (in coins) on that quiz.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was originally thinking, but then thought I needed to represent it as a way similar to "conditional on winning, this is the expected number of coins you would receive"